# Creación de contenedores en docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, contenedores

[image: crear un contenedor en docker]

Hola comunidad, necesito resolver una duda, estoy intentando crear un contenedor con las variables de entorno de mongo en docker, pero me sale ese error de referencia que el nombre debe ser en minúscula: (el nombre es mongoproyect y esta en minúscula como se ve, aun así me da el error de referencia invalida)

Comment: Te falta especificar `-e` antes en tu segunda variable de entorno (`-e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password'`).

Answer (score 1):

Su error está que en cada nombre de variable de entorno debe colocar el flag `-e`, además tiene un error en el mapeo del puerto, debe dejar un espacio luego del `-p` para que docker tome como parámetros el 27017:27017

puede probar así:

```
docker create -p 27017:27017 --name mongoproyect -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=mike -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password mongo
```

Eso debería bastar